# AngularJS Calculated field from hidden fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm creating a form in angularJS  with a calculated field whose value is given from 3 numeric field, one of which is hidden, and it's visibility depends on the input of another.

My problem is that as long as the third field is not visible, the value of the calculated field is not shown.

I tried to set 0 as default value of the hidden field but this not resolve the problem

This is my code:

```html
<input type="number" ng-model="currForm.A" name="r_A" required /><br />
<input type="number" ng-model="currForm.B" name="r_B" required /><br />
<div ng-show="currForm.B > '5' ">
  <input type="number" ng-model="currForm.C" name="r_C" ng-required="currForm.B > '5' " /><br />
</div>
<label>Risultato A+B+C</label>: <input type="number" ng-model="currForm.risultato"/>
```

And this is my script

```js
$scope.currForm.C = 0;

$scope.$watch(' currForm.A + currForm.B + currForm.C', function (value) { 
    $scope.currForm.risultato= value;
});

$scope.$watch("currForm.B<'5'",function(){ 
    $scope.currForm.C = "";
});
```

There is a way to do the calculation even if third input is hidden?

Thank you all

Comment: Would you mind to create a plunker? The hidden field is truly hidden, not removed. Therefore, its value should be available

Also, how did you set the default value?

Comment: `$scope.currForm.C = 0;` set the default value to 0.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/erm8U/)

Comment: I found the error:
When the input on second field is < 5 i reset the value to "", so my default value is overwritten!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the default value for `currForm.C = 0` but not in the watch section, change the second watch to following, it works for me:

```
$scope.$watch("currForm.B<'5'",function(){ 
    $scope.currForm.C = 0;
});
```